# Scanner Not Completing During For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to write some code that analyzes several pieces of text, but I found an issue with the scanner method. Here is my relevant code:

```
public static void getInput(Scanner key) {
    //This method takes the input of the user and makes it usable, controls all other methods, and prints findings
    System.out.print("\nHow many pieces of text do you want to analyze? ");
        
    int textNumb = key.nextInt(); 
        
    for( int i = 1; i <= textNumb; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter text sample number " + i + ": "); 
            
        key.nextLine(); 
        String textInput = key.nextLine();
            
        System.out.print("text has been received\n");   //this does not print after first round
            
        int sentences = getSentences(textInput); 
        int words = getWords(textInput); 
        int syllables = countSyllables(textInput); 
            
        printResults(sentences,words,syllables,textInput); 
    }
}
```

After the first round of the for loop, the scanner gets stuck and the program pauses completely. If I hit enter again after entering my text after the first round, none of the text actually gets processed by the rest of the methods. What can I do to fix this without closing and re-opening the scanner? Thank you.

Comment: You have an extra `readLine()` presumably to skip over the rest of the line following your `nextInt()`. But you only do the `nextInt` once; you don't need the extra `readLine()` inside your loop. Move it to before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the extra call to `key.nextLine()` without an assignment to a variable is because you probably encountered the issue described here: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

However, when implementing the workaround described there, you have to consider that you are using a loop. Keeping that in mind, you will only have to read the newline once after the `nextInt()` and after that in the loop, there is no point for the extra `nextLine()`. So the snippet should be:

```java
int textNumb = key.nextInt();
key.nextLine(); // consume newline once, outside the loop

for (int i = 1; i <= textNumb; i++) {
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter text sample number " + i + ": "); 
    String textInput = key.nextLine(); // read input inside the loop
    ...
}
```